# Font Awesome or Web Fonts not Showing on Website

Tags: font-awesome, webfonts, webfaction

I've been struggling for the better part of a year trying to get the Font Awesome web icon font to work on WebFactions servers. Every suggested "workaround" has been a bust and I'm not fully understanding why this is happening. I've contacted them and received information about creating a symlink to the folder app. Great...I did it...still not working. So far no one can offer any kind of valuable advice so I've moved my efforts here.

The site I'm currently working on [is this one](http://brdankepro.com/).

- The entire FontAwesome folder is inside of all of my projects and linked accordingly
- My implementation is good. Even themes I download from ThemeForest have the same issue on WF
- Ran a test on GoDaddy's servers and everything shows up fine.

Has anyone run into this problem with WebFaction or another host? And, if so, how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got the solution:

WebFaction requires both the use of a SymLink and the htaccess rule:

```
<IfModule mod_header.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|css)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```